# Organising tests in better way using a token from FE

Tags: javascript, cypress, web-api-testing

I'm currently testing a couple of microservices using Cypress. To test the REST api's, I need a token to make the requests. This token is available only via a local FE - image given below

[image: Token Image]

I have to access this FE to fetch the token only - there is no other way to access this access token.

Right now I'm doing it like this

```
describe('Do some test',()=>{
    it('first test',()=>{
    //this fetches the value of the token from FE.

     cy.get('css locator of the access token').invoke('val').then((token)=>{
       let tok = token;
      cy.request({
        method: 'GET' //or POST
        url: "http://localhost:3001/v1/api1.json",
        headers:{
         "Authorization": "Bearer "+token;
         "Content-Type":"application/json"
            }
               }).as('firsttest').then(()=>{
                             cy.get('@firsttest').its('status').should('eql',200);               
                                           })
          })
     })
})
```

Now this works and I get the correct status and all, but I know this is not a good way of organising tests and also it leads to a lot of duplication, because I have to fetch the token again and again if I am moving out of the `it` block.

How can I organise this in a way that I can fetch the `token` value once and then use it in my tests.. some thing like this

```
describe('Do first test',()=>{
     beforeEach(()=>{
     cy.get('get locator of the token').invoke('val').then((token)=>{
        let tok = token;
     })
})

   it('fetch and use token',()=>{
      cy.request({
      method: 'GET' //or POST
      url : 'http://someurl/path',
      headers :{
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+token;  (from beforeEach block)
      }
     })
   })

it('do another test using same token',()=>{
   //do something
 })

})
```

Or further simply in such a way that the duplicity of getting the the `token` is minimised.

Comment: So you basically want to ensure *all* `cy.request` calls automatically supply the `Auhtorization` header? Would a combination of `before` (to get the token), and overriding the `cy.request` (to ensure the header is set) work in your case?

Comment: I think yeah that is the gist.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom method inside support/command.js. for example ,here a custom method named 'Newlogin' has been created

```
Cypress.Commands.add('Newlogin', (email, password,env) => {
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'loginViaAuth0',
    });
        const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: env+'/oauth/token',   // Token Url
        failOnStatusCode: false,
        form:true,
        "body":'grant_type=password&userName='+email+'&Password='+password+'
      }; 
      cy.request(options)  
  });
```

Now you can access this method anywhere chaining with cy. for example

```
cy.Newlogin(username, password, env) /*Custom method defined in supports/command.js */
            .its('body')
            .then((resp) => {
                resp = JSON.stringify(resp)
                cy.log(resp)
                const token = JSON.parse(resp).access_token
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comments, here's a working example. It presupposes that the UI containing the token will always exist in every test.

Trouble with this solution is that putting the token-retrieval logic into `beforeEach` will effectively prevent `cy.visit` at the start of test. So, either put the `cy.visit` into the `beforeEach` (above the `cy.get()`), or come up with a different solution.

```js
// cypress/support/index.js

// override the `cy.request` to automatically supply the Authorization header
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
const AuthorizationToken = Symbol();
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('request', (origFn, ...args) => {
  // normalize arguments
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  let opts;
  if ( args.length === 1 ) {
    opts = typeof args[0] === 'string' ? { url: args[0] } : args[0];
  } else {
    opts = args.length === 2
      ? { url: args[0], body: args[1] }
      : { method: args[0], url: args[1], body: args[2] }
  }
  // set the Auhtorization header (if exists)
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  if ( cy.request[AuthorizationToken] ) {
    opts.headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cy.request[AuthorizationToken],
      ...opts.headers
    };
  }
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  return origFn(opts);
});

beforeEach(() => {
  // (1) setup (for demonstraion purposes)
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  cy.document().then( doc => {
    doc.body.innerHTML = '<div class="token">2as24flx9</div>';
  });
  // (2) actual code
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  cy.get('.token').invoke('text').then( token => {
    cy.request[AuthorizationToken] = token;
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a small clarification needed -The `beforeEach` block has to be inside the `describe` section of the tests right? Or are you including that inside the `index.js` file itself.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be. Mocha allows that.